# [PHP]Regex Expression To Split A Specific String

Tags: php, regex

i want to know something about RegEx, yeah I'm a new ReGex user. Okay here is my problem.
I have a string like this

```
< a href = 'howdy.html' class     =  'pt-nght' >
```

and I want to get an array that contains

`array[0] = "href = 'howdy.html'"`

`array[1] = "class = 'pt-nght'"`

I tried to use this ReGex

```
 [^<\s*(.*)]\s*(.*)\s*=\s*(.*)\s*[^>]
```

but the result seems to be far away from what i expect. Or may be there is any other technique ?
Thank you :)

Comment: Sounds like you're going down a dark path towards this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: There is other technique, sure. It is DOM parsing with DOM parser, without regexps... And sure you that `< a` is a valid element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a better time using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), but you could also try:

```
[^\s]+?\s*=\s*'.*?'
```